# Turn Dict of Arrays to Array of Dicts with all unique combinations from the Dict of arrays

Tags: arrays, dictionary, julia

I have a Dict of arrays that I want to turn into an array of Dicts where each Dict will have a unique combinations from the Dict of arrays. Ideally there would be a solution that would work with an arbitrary number of Dict keys and in a similar fashion to R's `expand_grid` (but for Dicts rather than DataFrames). In the below example I show an example dict of arrays that I want to turn into an array of Dicts.

```
d  = Dict{String,Array{Int}}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [[1,2,3], [4], [5,6]])

desired_result = Array{Dict{String,Int}}([Dict{String,Int}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [1,4,5]),
                                          Dict{String,Int}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [1,4,6]),
                                          Dict{String,Int}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [2,4,5]),
                                          Dict{String,Int}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [2,4,6]),
                                          Dict{String,Int}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [3,4,5]),
                                          Dict{String,Int}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [3,4,6])])
```

Of course one way would be appending to an array with nested for loops but it would be great if there was a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a 2-liner:

```
d= Dict{String,Array{Int}}(["a", "b", "c"] .=> [[1,2,3], [4], [5,6]]);

ks= sort(collect(keys(d)));
[Dict(ks .=> val) for val in (collect(Iterators.product(getindex.((d,),ks)...))...,)]
```

This yields:

```
6-element Array{Dict{String,Int64},1}:
 Dict("c"=>5,"b"=>4,"a"=>1)
 Dict("c"=>5,"b"=>4,"a"=>2)
 Dict("c"=>5,"b"=>4,"a"=>3)
 Dict("c"=>6,"b"=>4,"a"=>1)
 Dict("c"=>6,"b"=>4,"a"=>2)
 Dict("c"=>6,"b"=>4,"a"=>3)
```